How to detect StripedFly malware in Ubuntu 22.04?
I was reading this article, and decided to search for sd-pam in the processes of one of my laptops.
I did ps -x | grep -i "sd-pam", and got
2864 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
29172 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -i sd-pam

So I think I've got infected with this malware somehow. The laptop is old, and I remember during covid times my camera working without being user-activated (light was on), but I could never find out why.
I'm not an expert, nor even an experienced user/cybersecurity guy.
How does on confirm whether the laptop is infected or not with this malware?
PS: the article is in french. Here's also an article in english.

@mpboden I've reused part of the text and links in that question. That question doesn't answer this one... In fact, in the comments, I was advised to open a question specifically to ask for how to detect in Ubuntu.

Why do you think sd-pam is the malware? Incidentally I have sd-pam running in the background too in my 24.04 system.

@ArchismanPanigrahi yes this was already pointed out in comments on the OP's previous (unanswered) question How to remove StripedFly malware from Ubuntu 22.04? - the presence of the sd-pam process is by no means indicative.

Use locate sd-pam, and dpkg -S sd-pam, and sudo lsof -p2864.

sd-pam itself is no virus. It is a systemd services that execute in a PAM session. services with PAMName= in its unit will have a sd-pam process in its cgroup. The purpose is to wait for a service to terminate so it can perform a 'close PAM session'.
The thing to do is to search your services for PAMName (sudo grep -R PAMNAME /etc/systemd/system/*) and then find out if this usage is correct. Crypto miners use it a lot to keep the process active. Same goes for StripedFly: it claims to be a crypto miner but it is not; uninstalling keeps this active on your machine.

The cause for this problem is a bug in SAMBA v1. Samba v1 was already obsolete in 2014 so nobody should be using it. For disabling v1 see for instance:

How to find if SMBv1 is disabled in my ubuntu 14.4?

How to force SMB2 protocol in samba?

SMBv1 and Ubuntu


